# convert ArrayList<Object> to ArrayList<AnotherType>

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a Interface:

```
public interface ICentrala extends Remote{
    int registerGate(Object gate) throws RemoteException;
}
```

And classes:
Class "Gate":

```
public class Gate{
    int number;
    int in=0;
    int out=0;
...
}
```

Class "Centrala"

```
    ...
ArrayList<Object> listaBramek = new ArrayList<Object>();
    ...    
    public int registerGate(Object bramka)   {
    listaBramek.add(bramka);
    return 0;
    }
    ...
```

Now for example i want to add 2 gates :

```
Gate gate1 = new Gate();
gate1.number=1;
Gate gate2 = new Gate();
gate2.number=2;
registerGate(gate1)
registerGate(gate2)
```

And now i want to get all names of existing gates. What i have tried is :

```
public void getGates(){
    for (Object object: listaBramek){
        System.out.println(object)
    }
}
```

But in object in system.out.println "number" is not exsist after .
I cant do any changes in Interface.
Thank you in advance for Your help

Comment: Why does the method `registerGate` take any `Object` as an argument and why do you use an `ArrayList<Object>` at all? why not use the `Gate` class to register Gates as the name suggests? This smells like horrible design.

Comment: Why does it have to be an array of Object ? The only solution I can see is using instanceof keyword, but as many stated in the past, if you're forced to use instanceof outside an equals() function, then you probably should completely re-think your design.

Comment: Interface ICentrala with method registerGate is imposed by my teacher

Comment: In that case I would like to offer my condolences for having a teacher that teaches bad practices.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS not necessarily. The teacher may be trying to teach what problems you get when you don't choose your method signatures carefully. Or he/she might be building up to the use of generics, and just using Object as a catch-all before showing how generic parameters make things much easier.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand You fully, but you could override the toString() method in class Gate:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "gate number: " + number;
}
```

Comment: There is no issue with using `int` as an argument for `System.out.println()`. The problem is that when he cycles through the contents of the list, the app thinks he's working with `Object` which does not have `number` variable, even though the stored objects are `Gate`. See my answer.

Comment: @Dropout `System.out.println(Object obj)` will call the `toString()` method of `obj` (unless `obj` is null). So the above solution would work in producing the correct output.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS oh I see now. Isn't it a bit unnecessary to override base methods just because he wants some value from the object? Sorry if I'm wrong but the way he uses it in his example is just a mistake and not intended. Feels like you can just ask for the specific variable from the object and you don't have to change stuff like that. I know you only wrote it like that because it was in the question and what you described works of course, but getting the precise thing he needs seems like a less confusing thing to do (considering the guy's at school).

Comment: @MauricePerry you got a point there, depending on how restrictive/flexible you want the class to be. Let's not get philosophical though :)

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to create a getter method in the `Gate` class like this:

```
public int getNumber(){
    return number;
}
```

and then after you fill `listaBramek` list with `Gate` objects you can cycle through them and print out the value after casting to a `Gate` object

```
for(Object object : listaBramek){
    System.out.println(((Gate) object).getNumber());
}
```

The cast is necessary because `Object` does not have a `number` variable defined, `Gate` object does and is an extension of the `Object` class. When you cycle how you do it, even though they are `Gate` objects you work with them as if they were generic `Object` because of the

```
Object object:listaBramek
```

This isn't however optimal and is prone to run-time errors because the `listaBramek` list isn't restrictive enough - it should only allow `Gate` objects to be stored in it, unless you are willing to do further fail-safes.